# Working with dataTables and Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I have a **dataTable** with 200+ records in which each row there's button to delete that record, when the button is pressed a modal from **Bootstrap** pops up.

The problem is when I change "page" with the pagination option from dataTable the information inside the modal is not being updated with the corresponding ID. When I click in any row from the 1st page it works ok, but when I change page is when the information gets stucked with the last id I pressed from the first page.

Any ideas?

Mi code looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablewithtooltip" id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn delete-smt-btn" data-toggle="modal" id="111">Delete Row</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some info</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn delete-smt-btn" data-toggle="modal" id="112">Delete Row</a>
      </td>
      <td>Some info</td>
    </tr>

    ...

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('body').on('hidden', '#myModal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});

var table = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "aaSorting": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página"
    }
});

$('.delete-smt-btn').on('click', function(e){
    id = e.currentTarget.id;
    url = "mypage.com/something?p_something=" + id;

    $('#myModal').modal({
        remote : url
    });
    $('#myModal').removeData();
});

// I have some tooltips on my table, and I was having kind of the same issue when
// I changed pages with dataTable, the tooltip wasnt showing and I solved it with
// this but I cant make it work with modal.

    table.$('[rel="tooltip"], [data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({
      html: true
    }).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try attaching a delegated event listener to your table. The event handler is being attached to your buttons when the table initially renders, however when you page through the table, those buttons are destroyed and new ones are created. These new buttons are created after the handler was assigned, so they aren't listening for the `click` event.

It's also best practice to use delegated event listeners for cases like this where you have many elements firing the same function on the same event. Delegated events only assign one handler, otherwise you are assigning one handler per element, which will impact memory/performance

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', '.delete-smt-btn', function(e){
    id = e.currentTarget.id;
    url = "mypage.com/something?p_something=" + id;

    $('#myModal').modal({
        remote : url
    });
    $('#myModal').removeData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is most general solution 
[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMofRZ?p=preview)

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```